# Proof of $\cos5\theta =\cos3\theta$ if and only if$\theta= \frac{n\pi}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos5\theta =\cos3\theta$$ if and only

$$\theta= \frac{n\pi}{4}$$

If $\cos5\theta =\cos3\theta$,

then $\cos3\theta -\cos5\theta=0$

$2\sin4\theta \sin \theta=0$

therefore  $\sin4\theta=0$ or $  \sin \theta=0$

Thus $\theta = \frac{n\pi}{4}$ or $\theta =n\pi$

My question : What is wrong with the second solution ?

Comment: Alternate solution:

Cosine is an even function, so $\cos x=\cos -x$

$$5\theta=\pm 3\theta +2k\pi, \theta \in \{k\pi\}\lor \theta \in \{k\frac \pi 4\}:\theta \in \{k\frac \pi 4\}, k \in \mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing "wrong" with it, but it is subsumed by the first one.

Perhaps labeling them with different letters will make it clear:

$$\theta = \frac \pi 4 n \qquad \theta = \pi k$$

These assume $n,k$ are integers. If $n=4k$ (that is, any multiple of $4$), notice that you just get something of the second type. That is to say, any solution of the second type *is also a solution of the first type*, making stating the "second" solution set redundant.